# MySQL optimization - 7.5m rows

Tags: mysql, select, optimization, large-data

I have one table in MySQL with 7 500 000 rows and I have problem with duration of query. Can anyone help me with some tips to make it faster?
Table is called "attendance". It has indexses on col movement_date, employee_id and I tried to create index on both of the cols in one. However query below takes about 9 seconds and it is too slow for me. Has anyone some tips? I need to make this select with more than 14 employee ids.

```
SELECT * 
FROM attendance 
WHERE movement_date >= '2014-09-01 00:00:00' 
AND movement_date <= '2014-10-01 23:59:59' 
AND employee_id IN (14 integer ids...);
```

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `attendance` (
  `attendance_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `attendance_raw_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `employee_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `shift_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `shift_plan_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `record_status_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT ''1'',
  `movement_date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `attendance_movement_type_id` tinyint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `note` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_d` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_w` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_w` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`attendance_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `IDX_attendance_raw_id` (`attendance_raw_id`),
  KEY `IDX_employee_id` (`employee_id`),
  KEY `FK_attendance3` (`attendance_movement_type_id`),
  KEY `IDX_movement_date` (`movement_date`),
  KEY `FK_attendance4` (`record_status_id`),
  KEY `FK_movement_date_employee` (`movement_date`,`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_attendance` FOREIGN KEY (`employee_id`) REFERENCES `employee` (`employee_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_attendance2` FOREIGN KEY (`attendance_raw_id`) REFERENCES `attendance_raw` (`attendance_raw_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_attendance3` FOREIGN KEY (`attendance_movement_type_id`) REFERENCES `attendance_movement_type` (`attendance_movement_type_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_attendance4` FOREIGN KEY (`record_status_id`) REFERENCES `record_status` (`record_status_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=9072724 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CHECKSUM=1 DELAY_KEY_WRITE=1 ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC
```

Comment: Use `explain` to see where you  need an index.

Comment: Add the table definition into the question `show create table attendance` will give you the complete definition.

Comment: Yes looks like you have a composite index `FK_movement_date_employee` and it should be taken into account. Can you delete the index `IDX_employee_id` and then try see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the speed of result you need to change your sql statement in this way

```
SELECT * 
FROM attendance 
WHERE movement_date >= '2014-09-01 00:00:00' 
AND movement_date <= '2014-10-01 23:59:59' 
AND employee_id IN(
                   SELECT  indexed_column_IDs
                   FROM    table2 ...
                   )
```

Starting from a certain number of records, the IN predicate over a SELECT becomes faster than that over a list of constants.